# Is there a way to load sql data types into a drop down without having to write my own method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I would like to create a drop down similar to the drop down for sql data types in the  data mapping section in the Import/Export Wizard in Sql Management Studio.

Does anyone know how to do this without writing custom code to do so? Would there be a method call in System.Data.Sql that would perform this?

Comment: If you want to populate a drop down then you will need to write at least SOME code.

Comment: I was looking for a method that would return at least a collection. I wasn't looking for a 100% solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for posterity, this is not that hard to do - run this in Linqpad with a reference to `System.Data`:

```
void Main()
{
     Console.WriteLine(GetSqlTypes());
}

Dictionary<string,Type> GetSqlTypes()
{
   var types=new Dictionary<string,Type>();
   var a = Assembly.Load("System.Data");
     foreach (var sqlType in a.GetTypes().Where(t=>t.Namespace=="System.Data.SqlTypes" 
                    && t.Name.StartsWith("Sql")
                     && !t.Name.Contains("Exception")
                     && !t.Name.Contains("Schema")
                     && !t.Name.Contains("Stream")))
         {
            types.Add(sqlType.Name,sqlType);
         }
         return types;
}
```

So you can just bind your dropdown to GetSqlTypes:

```
    ddlTypes.DataSource = GetSqlTypes();
    ddlTypes.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddlTypes.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddlTypes.DataBind();
```

Of course this is a pure brute-force hack and no doubt someone else has a more elegant way to do it, but this will at least get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks you. This was exactly what I was looking for. I was looking for a method that would at least return something that can be iterated through. I wasn't looking for a 100% solution but at least get me an 80%. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.Data.SqlDbType));

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method to do that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question asked about methods in the System.Data namespace to fill a combobox. There are none. It perfectly answers the question.